# Protect flash files

Tags: flash

I would like to protect my flash files.
I would like to block any decompilers,protect actionscript and also protect graphics.
Some time ago,I tried to decompile a swf and when I placed it inside a decompiler , it showed me a login form and no graphics.I believe that is the ultimate protection method.Do you have any idea what software can do that?

Comment: See this post for another possible answer,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896052/what-are-some-reliable-flash-obfuscators/21082901#21082901

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. I would say that you cant, really. The only thing you can do is to make it harder to decompile/open in the first place. But once you let someone access/download (Eg: use it) the SWF into a client (Eg: browser) then there already exists a copy of your code/assets on that client computer.

As long as its downloadable, its also breakable. It might take the less experienced a little extra effort, but its possible, as your "download client" (the browser again) has to be able to open it and run it, so will an advanced decompiler + many newer browsers includes extensions/plugins that will let you view and extra whats already loaded in the browsers-cache right now.

For further info about "obfuscated code" look here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code

If you dont believe me, post any links you want us to test here as comments and I shall prove my point.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/developer-tools/fdt/buy-now/secureswf/